# Display only two subcategories under subcategories on frontpage

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I have many subcategories under sub categories. But i want only first two subcategories to be displayed on home page. Please guide how can i do without deleting the subcategories.
I have used web and people extension to customize the display on categories and subcategories[image]

Comment: you want to show the cardio and boxing only?

Comment: in one subcategory i want to display only two subcategories,, like under cardio only treadmill and cross Trainer to be displayed

Comment: second level or third level?

Comment: in third level it should display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to catalog->Manage Categories make following changes which you don't want to display in navigation

> Include in Navigation Menu = No.

Comment: Thank u,, i got what i was needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you not need to delete any subcategory instead you just need to do some R&D in admin system configuration. Where i'm sure the extension you have been using webAndPeople must have created a tab. You just need to modify its setting to define how many ***levels of categories*** it should display. That's it.
Clear all cache if enabled before testing in frontend.